# Loop through array of file urls and download each one with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, download

I'm trying to do what I 'thought' would be a simple task.  I have an array of URLs that I'd like to loop through and download on to the client machine when the user clicks a button.

Right now I have a parent component that contains the button and an array of the urls (in the state) that I'd like to loop through and download.  For some reason, the way I'm doing it now only downloads one of the files, not all of the contents of the array.

Any idea how to do this correctly within React?

```
handleDownload(event){
        var downloadUrls = this.state.downloadUrls;
        downloadUrls.forEach(function (value) {
            console.log('yo '+value)
        const response = {
              file: value,
        };                
            window.location.href = response.file;

        })
    }
```

Comment: why are you calling slice on downloadUrls?

Comment: Because I have an array of URLs in my state.  downloadUrls = ["http://file1", "http://file2", "http://file3"].  Users are able to select checkboxes of files that they would like to download before clicking the parent "Download all selected" button.

Comment: thats not an answer. what is the use or the point of calling slice? what are you trying to accomplish there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use setTimeout to wait a little bit between downloading each files.

```
handleDownload(event){
    var downloadUrls = this.state.downloadUrls.slice();
    downloadUrls.forEach(function (value, idx) {
        const response = {
          file: value,
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = response.file;
        }, idx * 100)
    })
}
```

In Chrome, this will also prompt the permission asking for multiple files download.

Comment: If URLs can be opened in a browser, this solution would open them instead of downloading.