# Downloading Documents From URL in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array with two URLs, these URLs download a PDF and a word document.
I am trying to loop through this array and call both of the URLs one after the other.
Now, if I call one or the other in this array then they download fine but if it tries to access one after the other it doesn't download both just the second one.

This is the block of code:

```
      if(this.links.length != 0)
        {
            this.links.forEach(element => {
                window.open(element,"_self");                 
            });
        }
```

Is there anyway to call both these URLs from the array and download both the documents from each?

Comment: are those link directly pointing to the PDF file itself? Well then this is the way to go.

Comment: They do not point directly to the documents. The URLs point to a back end that generates the documents.

Comment: I think most browser, especially chrome, have spam preventions enabled, that's why you won't be able to open too many tabs by looping through them. A possible solution could be to have the user interact with it each time (click a button per file), that would remove the prevention.

Comment: maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43749326/4479618

Comment: I'm not sure if its a possibility as I'm bound by requirements. But I could be left with no choice

Comment: I would rather put that to a backend solution to generate all the needed PDF with one request and zip them together, so it's more easily handle by each the frontend putting the requests, but also the backend as they don't have to struggle with too much requests at once.

Comment: So you hand over all the IDs/URIs as an JSON array to the backend and they return you and ZIP with all those files packed

Comment: That would be ideal but I didn't create the back end for this and it would require a lot more work to re-write it

Comment: Well these are the two points for me to consider, there's anything else to do there.